# rgbcolor.js unexpected token error, but I never touch the files

Tags: javascript, rgbcolor

I suddenly get this error

```
[!] (plugin commonjs) SyntaxError: Unexpected token (174:12) in A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rgbcolor\index.js    
node_modules\rgbcolor\index.js (174:12)
172:             re: /^rgba\((\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3}),\s*((?:\d?\.)?\d)\)$/,
173:             example: ['rgba(123, 234, 45, 0.8)', 'rgba(255,234,245,1.0)'],
174:             process: function (bits){  <- here
                 ^
175:                 return [
176:                     parseInt(bits[1]),
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (174:12) in A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rgbcolor\index.js
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:19607:13)
    at Parser.pp$9.unexpected (A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:16903:8)
    at Parser.pp$5.parseIdent (A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:19538:10)
    at Parser.pp$5.parsePropertyName (A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:19342:109)        
    at Parser.pp$5.parseProperty (A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:19269:8)
    at Parser.pp$5.parseObj (A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:19223:21)
    at Parser.pp$5.parseExprAtom (A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18958:17)
    at Parser.pp$5.parseExprSubscripts (A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18774:19)       
    at Parser.pp$5.parseMaybeUnary (A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18740:17)
    at Parser.pp$5.parseExprOps (A:\MyWorkFolder\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18667:19)
```

yet, I never touch or change the files, nor used anything from it (I think not recently).
Anybody ever have the same problem?

Comment: What is there in the file at that line/column?

Comment: @AHaworth i edited my question with the line

Comment: What is in the actual file at that line/column?

Comment: @AHaworth `process: function (bits){`